# Change another directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives to format text of elements.

```
 app.directive("kilometersText", function(){
     // writes number as kilometer
 })

 app.directive("metersText", function(){
     // writes number as meter
 })
```

HTML:

```
 <ul> 
     <li ng-repeat="item in data"> 
         <span kilometers-text="item.length"></span> 
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I have two buttons that change view to meter or kilometer.

```
<button type="button"> meter </button>
<button type="button"> kilometer </button>
```

How can I change directive with these buttons?

Comment: I would go for a custom filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the attribute, i suggest to use two spans, one for showing in KMs and other in meters. and then hide them conditionally based on the selected view.

```
<ul> 
     <li ng-repeat="item in data"> 
         <span ng-show="item.view == 'kilometer'" kilometers-text="item.length"></span> 
         <span ng-show="item.view == 'meter'" kilometers-text="item.length"></span> 
     </li>
 </ul>
```